# Unit testing complex Symfony 2 forms

Tags: forms, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

Has anyone found a way to to unit test Symfony forms that rely on entity field types?

I have tried following this tutorial:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html

including this section on adding a type your form depends on:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html#adding-a-type-your-form-depends-on

However, it seems that the entity field type depends on a registry parameter, so I tried mocking the entity field type, but now phpunit is reporting additional errors.

As unit testing forms seems extremely important, it seems that someone out there has had to have found a way to make this work. But despite my extensive searching, I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Have you tried passing the entity id as the form values?

Comment: Currently, Symfony supports the EntityType out of the box, but doesn't have a proper way to unit test it: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15098.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow through the errors and get a test working, yes.

The setup you will eventually converge to will look something like this:

```
// this is the method to register additional form types as 
// in the article http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html#adding-a-type-your-form-depends-on
protected function getExtensions()
{
    $entity = $this->mockEntityType();

    return [
        new PreloadedExtension(
            [
                $entity->getName()  => $entity
            ],
            []
        )
     ];
 }
```

The actual work to have the type not blow up:

```
// extracted out double setup for clarity
private function mockEntityType()
{
    $manager = $this->prophesize('Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager');
    $registry = $this->prophesize('Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry');
    $metadata = $this->prophesize('Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\ClassMetadata');
    $repository = $this->prophesize('Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository');

    $repository->findAll()->willReturn([]);
    $manager->getClassMetadata(Argument::cetera())->willReturn($metadata->reveal());
    $manager->getRepository(Argument::cetera())->willReturn($repository->reveal());
    $registry->getManagerForClass(Argument::cetera())->willReturn($manager->reveal());

    return new EntityType($registry->reveal());
}
```

Note that this is using [the prohpecy mocking framework](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy) which is shipped with phpunit since [version 4.5.0](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/Release-Announcement-for-PHPUnit-4.5.0#new-features)

The shown code simply sets up everything to return an empty array for any entity repository. Change this to your needs.

Comment: Using the above I get:

The option "route_name" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "attr", "auto_initialize", ......

Any ideas why?

Comment: `route_name` doesn't ring a bell but you might need to also add a `FormTypeValidatorExtension` (or any other TypeExtensions that add option) to the PreloadedExtension. See the second constructor param of http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/Form/PreloadedExtension.html as well.